# JerseyTest Default port change to test REST WEB SERVICE

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey-test-framework

I made a test case to test my Rest Web Service. but in test case I am seeing that the request is going to default port of jersey test framework which is  `http://localhost:9998` whereas my service is register on `http://localhost:8080`. I am unable to find that how can I change its port to `8080`

```
public class UMServiceTest extends JerseyTest {


    @Override
    public Application configure() {
        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);
        return new ResourceConfig(UMService.class);
    }    


    @Test
    public void testFetchAll() {
        System.out.println(getBaseUri()+"==========");
        Response output = target("usermanagement").path("um").path("user").request().get();
        assertEquals("should return status 200", 200, output.getStatus());
        //assertNotNull("Should return list", output.getEntity());
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

you can give a command line arguments when you run the test such as,

Maven
**`mvn yourpack.UMServiceTest -Djersey.config.test.container.port=8080`**

or in eclipse you can pass this in run config '**Arguments**' tab

Answer (score 5):

You could change the Systemproperty from TestProperties for the JerseyTest too.

```
public class UMServiceTest extends JerseyTest
{
    static
    {
        System.setProperty("jersey.config.test.container.port", "0");
    }
...
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to kuhajeyan's answer here's maven config for JerseyTest port:

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                ....
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>jersey.config.test.container.port</name>
                        <value>4410</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Jersey 2.33, the `configure` method can be set as in the following example taken from the Jersey Docs

```java
@Override
protected Application configure() {
    // Find first available port.
    forceSet(TestProperties.CONTAINER_PORT, "0");

    return new ResourceConfig(Resource.class);
}
```

In case, the `configureDeployment` is used to specify the resource, the below approach can be used.

```java
  @BeforeClass
  public static void beforeClass() {
    System.setProperty(
        // Use a random available port
        "jersey.config.test.container.port", String.valueOf(SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort()));
  }

  @AfterClass
  public static void afterClass() {
    System.clearProperty("jersey.config.test.container.port");
  }

  @Override
  protected DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
    return ServletDeploymentContext.forServlet(
            new ServletContainer(ResourceConfig.forApplicationClass(TestApplication.class)))
        .contextPath("/cas/api")
        .build();
  }
```

Source: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/test-framework.html#parallel